# Is there a way to change an audio file's speed in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, audio

Is there a way to change the speed of an audio file (by rewriting it, or some similar means) in Android Studio (using Java)? I want to be able to take an mp3 file and output a file at 1.5x speed. I've looked around, but I've only been able to find explanations about how to change playback speed, not how to change the file itself.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why would you use Android Studio for that? It is program for writing android applications, not for audio file management.

Comment: @МилошКојадиновић I need Android Studio because it is for a component of a much broader application.

Comment: If you need to create altogether new, separate files from an mp3 file, the first step is going to be decoding it to PCM. I'd start by doing a search on that process.